# How to write a logic when double clicking on page using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a page in which I have a few elements. My scenario is, when I double click on the background i.e., not clicking on any of the elements. I need to go 1 page back using angular. I am pretty new to angular. I am trying to figure out a way to implement. Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Comment: if you are using ui-router (if not, you should) you simply navigate to another state. There's an angular directive `ng-dblclick`. You call an action from the controller and then redirect with the ui router

Comment: How can I do it when clicking on anywhere in the html body? (I am using a canvas for this page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has a native `dblclick` event, which is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick).

You'll need to check that the event is coming from the body itself, instead of one of the elements generating an event that then bubbles up to the body.

Try something like this, passing the body as the element:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
 element.on('dblclick', function(e) {
     if(e.target === element){
         $window.history.back();
     }
 });
}
```

Comment: The route is the same for both the pages.